# Error: Most middleware (like cookieParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I used cookie-parser and body-parser for node.js chat. I use code from [github](https://github.com/joshmarshall/uberchat) it won't run and it shows error

> Error: Most middleware (like cookieParser) is no longer bundled with
>   Express and must be installed separately.

The code is here

https://github.com/joshmarshall/uberchat

Comment: The message seems pretty clear - did you try what it tells you to do?

Answer (score 8):

For cookieParser, instead of this line:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser({"secret": config.cookieSecret}));
```

Install the cookie module for your project and use something like this:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser(config.cookieSecret))
```

All this information is available by just searching "npm cookieparser" and looking at the cookieparser doc.

Comment: ok thank u ... can u send some link for multiple chat like group and personal chat

Comment: @ManojK - You can look at the chat demo code that is documented on the [socket.io site](http://socket.io/).  If I have answered your original question, then please follow the stack overflow procedure and indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  For additional questions on a new topic, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install cookieParser separately. It because express no longer contains inside cookieParser (from 4 version).

After installing cookieParser via npm write in you app.js file `app.use(cookieParser());`

It should work.